# How do I show the following generates $H_1( \mathbb{R} P^2 ; \mathbb{Z}/ 2) $?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

Using this triangulation and denoting the oriented edge from i to j as $(i,j)$,
let $\alpha = (1,5) + (5,4) + (3,4) + (3,2) + (2,1) $. Why is $\alpha$ generating $H_1( \mathbb{R} P^2 ; \mathbb{Z}/ 2) $? First, if I write down, how an arbitrary chain looks like, I get: $\beta = \sum_i l_i \beta_i ; l_i \in \mathbb{Z} / 2  , \beta_i : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} P^2$ continuous. For a cycle, I can argue then, that $\beta$ has to be a closed curve. If I could argue somehow that without loss of generality $\beta$ has no self-intersections, I see that $\beta$ is homotopic to $\alpha$. But how do I do that?

Comment: I presume the lower left vertex is 5 and the lower right is 2?

Comment: Besides that, your question is still incomplete. Your question should be more specific, explaining what have you tried, and where you got stuck. Otherwise your potential answerers will be scared off by having to write a long complicated explanation which you probably already understand 75% of. For example, do you know how to write down the chain complex? If not, where did you get stuck on that? If so, where did you get stuck computing the homology group?

Comment: @LeeMosher, about the vertices you're right and I've edited my question. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{Z}/2)$?

Comment: I only know it for $H_1 (\mathbb{R}P^2, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I don't mean the final answer. I mean the step-by-step process by which one calculates homology groups. If you don't know that process, then the best I can recommend is that you learn it.

Comment: I know how to do it for CW/Simplicial complexes by cellular/simplicial homology. But not how to do it with other coefficients. Do you mean sth. else? Where could I find that in, e.g. Hatcher?

Comment: Yes, Hatcher is a good place.

Comment: And working with coefficients $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is no different than with $\mathbb{Z}$, except of course all the additions and multiplications are taking place in $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is about as simple as arithmetic ever gets.

Comment: Okay, so I am a bit confused. What I know and what I think how Hatcher approaches a lot of computation is by the cellular chain complex, but only with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. One then simply takes the cellular chain complex with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2$ ? Or what exactly do you mean by "step by step process" for computing homology?